# Want to create Record in batch class and there is no record to query in start method

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous

I had one batch class in which i am passing some data required for creating object record.But when i call that batch class from parent class variables are initialized but start method are not called as there is no record to query i also tried with iterable object but not able to do that.My code is as below

```
global class testBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,Database.Stateful{
    public List<sObject> sObjectList;
    public string objectName;
    public String dataList;

    public testBatchClass(String objectName,String inputdata){

        String listType = 'List<'+objectName+'>';
        system.debug('list type value is'+listType);
        List<SObject> castRecords = (List<SObject>)Type.forName(listType).newInstance();
        this.sObjectList = castRecords;
        this.objectName = objectName;
        this.dataList = inputdata;

    }
    global Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {
        return new sObjectList{};
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<sobject> scope){

        List<OpportunityRenewal__mdt> mdtList = new List<OpportunityRenewal__mdt>([Select id,Api_Name_of_Fields__c,Sobject_Name__c from TestFileUploadCustomSetting1__mdt where Sobject_Name__c=:objectName]);
        List<String> fieldName = new List<String>();
        for(OpportunityRenewal__mdt md : mdtList){
            if(md.Sobject_Name__c == objectName){
                fieldName = md.Api_Name_of_Fields__c.Split(',');
                break;
            }
        }
        List<String> dataRowsSplit= dataList.split(',');
        dataRowsSplit.remove(0);
        for(String eachRow: dataRowsSplit){
            List<String> splitString = eachRow.Split(',');
            sObject sobj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).newSObject();
            for(Integer i=0; i <= splitString.Size(); i++){
                sobj.put(fieldName[i],splitString[i]);
            }
            scope.add(sobj);
        }
        if(scope != Null && scope.Size() > 0){
            upsert scope;
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Execute method will only be executed when the returned list of sObjects has at least one element (and it will be executed as many times as necessary based on its length and the batch-size).

My suggestion is that you put the `for(String eachRow: dataRowsSplit){}` also on the start, so you can add to your `sObjectList` as many instances as records you would like to process.
Then you can really use the scope to pass the "original empty sObject" and fill it in your execute before doing the upsert.

The end result would be something like... (might not compile but will give you the idea)

```
global class testBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,Database.Stateful{
    global class testBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,Database.Stateful{
        public List<sObject> sObjectList;
        public string objectName;
        public String dataList;

        public testBatchClass(String objectName,String inputdata){

            String listType = 'List<'+objectName+'>';
            system.debug('list type value is'+listType);
            List<SObject> castRecords = (List<SObject>)Type.forName(listType).newInstance();
            this.sObjectList = castRecords;
            this.objectName = objectName;
            this.dataList = inputdata;
            // Added
            List<String> dataRowsSplit= dataList.split(',');
            dataRowsSplit.remove(0);

            for(String eachRow: dataRowsSplit){
                sObject sobj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).newSObject();
                this.sObjectList.add(sobj);
            }   
        }
        global Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {
            return sObjectList; // changed
        }
        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<sobject> scope){

            List<OpportunityRenewal__mdt> mdtList = new List<OpportunityRenewal__mdt>([Select id,Api_Name_of_Fields__c,Sobject_Name__c from TestFileUploadCustomSetting1__mdt where Sobject_Name__c=:objectName]);
            List<String> fieldName = new List<String>();
            for(OpportunityRenewal__mdt md : mdtList){
                if(md.Sobject_Name__c == objectName){
                    fieldName = md.Api_Name_of_Fields__c.Split(',');
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(sObject sobj: scope){ // removed some parts
                List<String> splitString = eachRow.Split(',');
                for(Integer i=0; i <= splitString.Size(); i++){
                    sobj.put(fieldName[i],splitString[i]);
                }
            }
            upsert scope;
        }

        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {}
    }
}
```